# View Multiple Screen Support

Tags: android, view, bitmap, screen

I know there's a lot of info out there about this topic, but I still kinda confused. I made a class view for an android app, that works with bitmaps and text.

I define the text position like that:

```
canvas.drawText("SCORE: " + score, (canvas.getWidth() - 150),
                    (canvas.getHeight() - 20), paintScore);
```

per example, but I know it's not the best of way of doing it, because it look just like I want on my phone, but in one's with a smaller or a bigger screen it looks awful, or just out of the screen.

How should I be doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to choose your widths to position things relative to the size of the canvas - so figure out where you want the text to b on your phone - for instance, if you want it to begin at the center:

```
int x = canvas.getWidth()/2
```

If these relative type measurements don't work out as well, as a last resort, android specifies a special kind of resource (@dimen) that you can define in your various values folders (such as `values-small/dimen.xml` or `values-xlarge/dimen.xml`) and hard code integer values there. (As seen in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension)) and then retrieve them like you would any other resource:

```
getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.score_margin)
```

Comment: I tried as much as possible to use things like "canvas.getWidht/2", but in some situations it doesn't work well... Your second sugestions it's a little more complex, I think, but Im going to try it anyway. Thanks.

Comment: I tried to use the @dimen resources and it works really well. Thanks for the tip. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have many solutions :

1) work with density independent pixels (dip) :

here is a method to convert from px to dip :

```
public static int pxToDip(Activity activity, int size){

    Resources r = activity.getResources();
    int dipSize = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, size, r.getDisplayMetrics());

    return dipSize;

}
```

2) Work with percentage :

Get the screen size, compare it to your desired text size and add your margin in percent

Comment: hum, thanks, going to try this. Im also open to other sugestions, because for gaming development it's important to get the graphics great. :/